# How do I access the children of a TableView in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
            var tv = new TableView
            {
                Intent = TableIntent.Form,
                Root = new TableRoot
            {
                new TableSection
                {
                    new SwitchCell
                    {
                        Text = "Remember Me"
                    }
                }
            }
            };
```

How would I access the SwitchCell so that I can see the `On` property in Xamarin Forms

[More info on SwitchCell found here](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3AXamarin.Forms.SwitchCell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it:

```
SwitchCell sc = (SwitchCell)tv.Root[0][0];
bool booleanprop = sc.On;
```

Easy when you know how.